# JS function that compare today date to array of birthdays/holidays

Tags: javascript, arrays, innerhtml

I'm trying to create a JS function that compares today's date to an array of birthdays/holidays and display it into my static web page, below is my code...any suggestions?

I'm trying to to have it post into the webpage using innerHTML but it's not working, thanks so much for your help.

```
//array of special days
const specialDays = [
  //tech birthdays
  { name: "Sharon Wagner", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 8 },
  { name: "Lisa Vonhauser", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Coleen Druby", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 27 },
  { name: "Kayla Wilburn", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 1 },
  { name: "Anita Krivenko", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Tracy Schaffer", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 3 },
  { name: "Casey Wolf", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 29 },
  { name: "Jane Moyer", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Marissa Conti", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 16 },
  { name: "Nathan Heltebridle", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 17 },
  { name: "Cheyann Wasssel", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 17 },
  { name: "Jason Hatter", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 3 },
  { name: "Barbara Butler", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Marge Lopretto", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 14 },
  { name: "Mary Beth Hellberg", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 15 },
  { name: "Anne Tonkin", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Derek Knisely", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Dana Fortney", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 23 },
  { name: "Brad Mikitko", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 28 },
  { name: "Chuck Saltern", birthMonth: 6, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Bradlee Harvey", birthMonth: 6, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Russell DiCristina", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 5 },
  { name: "David Fortney", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 6 },
  { name: "Heather Raudenbush", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 8 },
  { name: "Anngel Rickrode", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 21 },
  { name: "Amanda Renninger", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 26 },
  { name: "Heather Pugh", birthMonth: 8, birthDate: 19 },
  { name: "Joan Hartman", birthMonth: 8, birthDate: 31 },
  { name: "Alexis Luna", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 4 },
  { name: "Jeremy Luong", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 7 },
  { name: "Lauryn Hench", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Dan Flannery", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Matt Getz", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Lizz Robb", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 20 },
  { name: "Debbie Lister", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Elizabeth Kurtz", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Andrew Ebersole", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Tricia Burns", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 6 },
  { name: "Robin Kline", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 14 },
  { name: "Julie Tobias", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 20 },
  { name: "Louis Kabamba", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 7 },
  { name: "Krista Rector", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Carly Klinedinst", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 27 },
  //holidays
  { name: "Happy New Year! ", holidayMonth: 1, holidayDate: 1 },
  { name: "Happy July 4th! ", holidayMonth: 7, holidayDate: 4},
  { name: "Merry Xmas! ", holidayMonth: 12, holidayDate: 25 },
];

//get today's date & month
const today = new Date();
const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
const date = today.getDate();

//function to compare today's date & month to array of birthdays

const birthDays = specialDays.find((it) => it.birthDate === date && it.birthMonth === month);
document.getElementById("birthday").innerHTML = birthDays;


const holidayDates = specialDays.find(it => it.holidayDate === date && it.holidayMonth === month);
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you separate the birthday array from the holiday array since they are different objects. In addition to that, if you expect a single object to match the current date, use `find()` . In the case of multiple objects (i.e. multiple people with same birthdate), use `filter()`

```js
//array of special days
const specialBirthDays = [
  { name: "Sharon Wagner", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 8 },
  { name: "Lisa Vonhauser", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Coleen Druby", birthMonth: 1, birthDate: 27 },
  { name: "Kayla Wilburn", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 1 },
  { name: "Anita Krivenko", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Tracy Schaffer", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 3 },
  { name: "Casey Wolf", birthMonth: 2, birthDate: 29 },
  { name: "Jane Moyer", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Marissa Conti", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 16 },
  { name: "Nathan Heltebridle", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 17 },
  { name: "Cheyann Wasssel", birthMonth: 3, birthDate: 17 },
  { name: "Jason Hatter", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 3 },
  { name: "Barbara Butler", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Marge Lopretto", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 14 },
  { name: "Mary Beth Hellberg", birthMonth: 4, birthDate: 15 },
  { name: "Anne Tonkin", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Derek Knisely", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Dana Fortney", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 23 },
  { name: "Brad Mikitko", birthMonth: 5, birthDate: 28 },
  { name: "Chuck Saltern", birthMonth: 6, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Bradlee Harvey", birthMonth: 6, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Russell DiCristina", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 5 },
  { name: "David Fortney", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 6 },
  { name: "Heather Raudenbush", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 8 },
  { name: "Anngel Rickrode", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 21 },
  { name: "Amanda Renninger", birthMonth: 7, birthDate: 26 },
  { name: "Heather Pugh", birthMonth: 8, birthDate: 19 },
  { name: "Joan Hartman", birthMonth: 8, birthDate: 31 },
  { name: "Alexis Luna", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 4 },
  { name: "Jeremy Luong", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 7 },
  { name: "Lauryn Hench", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Dan Flannery", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Matt Getz", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 13 },
  { name: "Lizz Robb", birthMonth: 9, birthDate: 20 },
  { name: "Debbie Lister", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Elizabeth Kurtz", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 2 },
  { name: "Andrew Ebersole", birthMonth: 10, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Tricia Burns", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 6 },
  { name: "Robin Kline", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 14 },
  { name: "Julie Tobias", birthMonth: 11, birthDate: 20 },
  { name: "Louis Kabamba", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 7 },
  { name: "Krista Rector", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 12 },
  { name: "Carly Klinedinst", birthMonth: 12, birthDate: 27 }
];

const specialHolidays = [
  { name: "Happy New Year! ", holidayMonth: 1, holidayDate: 1 },
  { name: "Happy July 4th! ", holidayMonth: 7, holidayDate: 5},
  { name: "Merry Xmas! ", holidayMonth: 12, holidayDate: 25 }
]

//get today's date & month
const today = new Date();
const month = today.getMonth() + 1;
const date = today.getDate();

//function to compare today's date & month to array of birthdays

const birthDays = specialBirthDays.filter((it) => it.birthDate === date && it.birthMonth === month);


const holidayDates = specialHolidays.find((holiday)=>holiday.holidayMonth == month && holiday.holidayDate == date)

console.log(birthDays, holidayDates)
```

Comment: Thanks! the codes work but only in Chrome, how do I make it so i can work on Internet Explorer?

Comment: [`Array.prototype.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Browser_compatibility) is not supported in IE. I suggest making a workaround ( either using `filter()` as well, or using for loops ).